# How to log redis pub/sub time?

Tags: redis

I try to use redis for pub/sub by two systems and one of them is now ours (other company maintain it). I would like to have time stamp when I publish something in redis channel. Can someone help with this idea?

1. I already user redis log with *debug* level of information (the highest one) - but there is no time info for pub/sub messages in the log.
2. I tested redis monitor: `redis-cli monitor` . It's exactly what I want, but it decrease the performance of the system by [50%](https://redis.io/commands/monitor#cost-of-running-monitor).
3. The only way is to implement the time log by myself - may be SET some time info before pub command in redis? This will put in redis local time and it will be slightly before pub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve the goal with pubsub.

You might want to try [Redis Streaming](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro). For each streaming message, the first part of the automatically generated ID is the Unix timestamp when the ID is generated, i.e. the message is received by Redis.